# Something wrong happens with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

New items are added to RecyclerView each time when Adapter have created.
In photo I showed a process where darken dish images appear, though I managed image darking with a condition `if(holder.mDish.getPicurl()!=null)`, but it doest work.

If I go into darken dish image details and go back to list, there will by three darken images. Is it problem with RecyclerView or it is my fault?

[image]

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mDish = DISHES.get(position);
    final int id = holder.mDish.getId();

   if(holder.mDish.getPicurl()!=null) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(holder.mDish.getPicurl())
                .fit()
                .transform(new RoundedTransformation(20, 0))
                .into(holder.mIvBackground);
        holder.mIvBackground.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    } else {
        holder.mIvBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_drawable_dish);
    }


    holder.mTvName.setText(holder.mDish.getName());
    //holder.mTvDescription.setText(holder.mDish.getDescription());
    holder.mTvPrice.setText("T " + String.valueOf(holder.mDish.getPrice()));
    holder.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mListener!=null){
                mListener.onAddToBasketInteraction(id);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onStartDetailActivity(id);
        }
    });
}


public void addDishes(List<Dish> dishes){
    DISHES.clear();
    DISHES.addAll(dishes);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public Dish mDish;
    public final View mView;
    public final ImageView mIvBackground;
    public final TextView mTvName;
    //public final TextView mTvDescription;
    public final TextView mTvPrice;
    public final ImageButton mBtnAdd;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mIvBackground = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishBackground);
        mTvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        //mTvDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        mTvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        mBtnAdd = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    }
}
```

**xml of item:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dishBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Плов узбекский"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="14sp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="T 3000"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_black_24dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You don't undo view changes in conditional statement

The culprit is this piece of code:

```
if(holder.mDish.getPicurl()!=null) {
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(holder.mDish.getPicurl())
            .fit()
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation(20, 0))
            .into(holder.mIvBackground);
    holder.mIvBackground.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
} else {
    holder.mIvBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_drawable_dish);
}
```

The way `RecyclerView` works is it reuses the same views with a different data (hence *recycler*), so the `onBindViewHolder` method may be called multiple times for each position, but the `ViewHolder` might have been already created and previously bound to a different piece of data. That way some changes applied to the view inside the `onBindViewHolder` method might persist through bind calls to different pieces of data.

In your case, the following call:

```
holder.mIvBackground.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

alters the view with the color filter within one call to `onBindViewHolder`. Then, when another piece of data is bound to the same `ViewHolder`, the condition `holder.mDish.getPicurl()!=null` might be false, but the effect still persists, because there is no removal of this color filter in the `else` branch of your statement.

#### Fix

You need to explicitly set **and unset** any changes to a single view in your `RecyclerView` for every separate condition you wish to implement:

```
if(holder.mDish.getPicurl()!=null) {
    holder.mIvBackground.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
} else {
    holder.mIvBackground.setColorFilter(null); // removes color filter
}
```

You don't see any problems with your `mIvBackground` because you set a different one in each branch of your if-else statement, so no unwanted state persists.